# Find string then print what comes next until another string

Tags: awk

Here's my `input.file` (thousands of lines):

```
FN545816.1  EMBL    CDS 9450    9857    .   +   0   ID=cds-CBE01461.1;Parent=gene-CDR20291_3551;Dbxref=EnsemblGenomes-Gn:CDR20291_3551,EnsemblGenomes-Tr:CBE01461,GOA:C9YHF8,InterPro:IPR003594,UniProtKB/TrEMBL:C9YHF8,NCBI_GP:CBE01461.1;Name=CBE01461.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=rsbW;product=anti-sigma-B factor (serine-protein kinase);protein_id=CBE01461.1;transl_table=11
```

I want to extract only what comes after `product=` up to the next `;`
So, in this case, I want to get "anti-sigma-B factor (serine-protein kinase)"

I tried this:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/*product=/) print $(i+1)}' input.file > output.file
```

but it prints only "factor" (presumably because there's no space in between "product=" and "anti-sigma-B". It doesn't print the rest neither.

I tried many previous solutions but none gave what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/product=[^;]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program here.
match($0,/product=[^;]*/){                      ##Using match function for awk here, where giving REGEX to match from string product= till first occurrence of ;
  print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)           ##Printing substring whose value is from RSTART+8 to till RLENGTH-8, where RSTART and RLENGTH are out of the box keywords which will be set once REGEX condition is satisfied. RSTART mean starting point of regex and RLENGTH is length of REGEX matched.
}'  Input_file                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly, thank you! Honestly, I did not get the `substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)` part.

Comment: @ThePresident, I had added explanation to my answer too, where `RSTART` is the starting index(point) of matched regex and `RLENGTH` is the length of that matched REGEX. So as we know `substr` is used to get sub string then it has starting point(from where it should cut string) I have put `RSTART` till `RLENGTH`, is it clear now please let me know in case of any queries?

Comment: Yeah makes sense now. Thank you.